# Criteria to perform Cross Validation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cross-validation

Now I know *why* we do Cross Validation. And *how* we do it. I have few questions around it though:

- Why can't we do that on every dataset we work on? Like, why shouldn't it be a standard, or a rule of thumb, if you may - "Instead of train-test split, do Cross Validation" ...
- Is there a certain size of dataset we need to consider before performing it? Like, can it be done on like dataset with 6 to 9 digit rows? If not, what's the alternate? Bootstrapping? I heard from someone that it may not perform well with huge dataset.
- Does it make sense in performing it on a heavily biased data set?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross Validation is not an alternative to a train-test split, but a method of training.  So you can do your train-test split, and then use cross validation within your training set (in particular to tune your hyperparameters), and once you have your final model use the test set to test it (something you only do once).

Comment: I would add to the rest of answers that cross validation may be risky in smaller datsets, as you may end up with very little data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can do it in every dataset you work on. The major drawback (and the reason why train-test split approach is  still widely used) is that CV is computationally expensive. If you are dealing with huge datasets and you use a n-fold CV, then the model has to be trained n times. On the contrary, with train-test it only has to be trained once.
- There is no specific criteria regarding the size of the dataset, although the smaller the dataset the less number of folds should be used. It is worth to point out  that 6 to 9 digit rows is minuscule amount of data to perform neither CV nor any other approach.
- If for heavily biased dataset you mean that imbalancement exists, then you should deal with it regardless of the performance assessment method used.

Comment: Thanks for your response. FYI, by 6 to 9 digit rows, I meant 999999 to 999999999 rows. Not 6 to 9 rows :)

Answer (score 2):

As @Henry pointed out Cross Validation is a method of training the model and figuring out the best set of parameters. If you just have 1 test set it can be that your hyperparameters are overfitted to that set.

• We always try to do cross-validation. If however, you have a large enough dataset that captures your data distribution well then it's not necessary to do cross-validation ( in cases of Big data ). This assumption heavily depends on the test set. Cross-validation takes a lot of time for computation since you have to tune K such models hence you avoid in cases when the time is of the essence.

• In small datasets one thing that's famous is setting K = size of data - 1 in cross-validation aka OOB error since you already have low enough data and should be trying to use each data point while modelling.

• I don't particularly understand what you mean biased. There are splitting like stratified that ensure the same distribution of labels is in the test dataset as compared to train